# change ftpd password viassh pure-ftpd

Tags: linux, ftp

Hi my cpanel license just ended up needed to change an user's ftp password via ssh

logged on as root and changed password by

```
passwd username
```

command but still i can login by old password to ftp :/

i use pure-ftpd / centos

what should i do for able to change ftp password

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've just done this on Debian-based Raspberry Pi OS with success:

```
sudo pure-pw passwd {username}
[ENTER NEW PASSWORD WHEN PROMPTED x 2]
sudo pure-pw mkdb
sudo service pure-ftpd restart
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following:

> pure-pw passwd user

Man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/8/pure-pw

Comment: Unable to open the passwd file: No such file or directory
Unable to fetch info about user [ahmet] in file [/etc/pureftpd.passwd]

:(

Comment: Did you run as root?